# Python,What's the difference of these two approaches of getting path？

Tags: python

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
print(path)
>>> /Users/***/Desktop/***/templates
path = os.path.abspath('templates')
print(path)
>>> /Users/***/Desktop/***/templates
```

I got confused about this, some one can explain this？

Comment: Your second example is basically equivalent to ``os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'templates')`` - relying on what the current working directory happens to be is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To notice the difference, you'll have to save the file and run it from a different path:

```
$ cat > path.py << EOF
import os
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
print(path)
path = os.path.abspath('templates')
print(path)
EOF
```

Output:

```
$ python path.py
/home/.../templates
/home/.../templates
```

But if you run it from another path:

```
$ cd another_path
~/another_path$ python ../path.py 
/home/.../templates
/home/.../another_path/templates
```

The first example returns the path relative to the file, but the second is relative to the current working directory (`getcwd`).

Answer (score 0):

Your first example gets the path from an *explicit* file name (the value stored in `__file__`), the second relies more *implicitly* on where you executed Python from.

The methods seem interchangeable when the values coincide which in your examples seems to be the case, but if the file in question was located somewhere a bit deeper in the architecture of your application or was part of another module external to your application you'd get something different.